# How to get the specified string in a sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a section as Note which contains the Patient Name and Patient Number I want to fetch Patient Name only. I tried using the CHARINDEX function but was able to fetch the Name along with the Phone written at the end. How can I try to remove the last 5 chars or optimize to fetch only the name from the column?

Input:

| Note |
| --- |
| Patient Name: John Mathews Phone Number: 1234567890 |

**Required Output:** `John Mathews`

Currently, I am using the following SQL query to get the output as:

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Note, CHARINDEX(':', Note)
    , CHARINDEX('Phone',Note) - CHARINDEX('Name', Note))
```

The output I have received is :

Output: `John Mathews Phone`

I want to remove the Phone part, I tried using various methods but was unable to find a proper solution for the same.
Can someone help me where should I make changes in the same function without using another substring to find the length and removing it from the end?

Comment: You have tagged MySQL and SQL Server - please correct. Good lesson in database design, structure your information correctly into columns, don't save multiple items of information in the same column.

Comment: Alternative approach to load data and extract required value in programming language of your application. Structured Query Language designed to retrieve **structured** data(tables, rows and columns), not searching a text. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data and description, the patient name always begins at position 15.  That makes this rather simple:

```
select substring(v.note, 15, charindex('Phone Number:', note) - 16)
```